# What are the invariant factors of $G \times G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, direct-product

> Let a finite abelian group $G$ have invariant factors $n_1, n_2, . . . , n_k$ . What are
> the invariant factors of $G \times G$?

**What I have done:** I used as an example the group $G=\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_4 $ whose invariant factors are $3$ and $12$. Then $G\times G$ has the invariant factors $3, 3, 12$ and $12$. Can I say that in general the invariant factors of $G\times G$ are just a combination of them? (That is, If $G$ have invariant factors $n_1, n_2, . . . , n_k$, then the invariant factors of $G\times G$ are $n_1, n_1, n_2, n_2, . . . , n_k,n_k$)

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups?

Comment: You can decompose $G$ as $C_{n_1}\times\cdots\times C_{n_k}$, where $n_1,\ldots,n_k$ are the invariant factors of $G$, so $n_1|\cdots|n_k$. What happens if you do that decomposition in $G\times G$?

Comment: @Shaun I have not explicitly seen that topic

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think what I say in my question is happening, Mr. Arturo. I'd have to $G\times G=C_{n_1}\times⋯\times C_{n_k} \times C_{n_1}\times⋯\times C_{n_k}$, Thus the invariant factor are $n_1,n_1,...,n_k, n_k$, and it is true that $n_1\mid \cdots \mid n_k$, no?

Comment: Yes, because it goes both ways: if the invaraiant factors are $m_1,\ldots,m_r$, then you can decompose $G$ as $G\cong C_{m_1}\times\cdots\times C_{m_r}$. And if you can decompose $G$ as $G\cong C_{\ell_1}\times\cdots\times C_{\ell_s}$, and $\ell_1|\ell_2|\cdots|\ell_s$, then $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_s$ are the invariant factors of $G$. That is, the decomposition is unique up to the order of the factors.